# Server Manager from Windows 2008 to Hyper-V 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access

My workstation is running Windows Server 2008. I do not have local admin privileges. I have a Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 (i.e. Core+Hyper-V) box. On that box, I do have local admin privileges.

I can Remote Desktop to the box; Hyper-V Manager works fine (outside of Server Manager). It's just that there are some things that are easier to do in Server Manager (partition disks, etc.) than at the command line.

I'd like to use Server Manager on my workstation to manage the Hyper-V box.

However:

- When I run Server Manager on my workstation, it prompts for elevation, and won't then let me connect to another server.
- If I attempt to run MMC and then add "Server Manager" as a Snap-in, it doesn't prompt me for the server name. Then it complains that I'm not an Administrator. It doesn't provide for connecting to another server.
- The Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) are for [Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9FF6E897-23CE-4A36-B7FC-D52065DE9960&displaylang=en) and [Windows 7 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=f6c62797-791c-48e3-b754-c7c0a09f32f3&displaylang=en). These don't install on Windows 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using the Hyper-V Administrator tool, outside of Server Manager?

There should be an entry for it in Control Panel->Administrative Tools.

Works a treat here for managing 5 Hyper-V host servers from my Server 2008 desktop (yes, I run Server 2008 as a desktop).

Comment: Hyper-V Administrator works fine. I would like to use Server Manager for disk management, etc.; updated question

Comment: I don't think Server Manager itself is supposed to work across systems - but each individual component can.

For example, in my original answer, you can run the Hyper-V component seperately and connect that to the other server, and this also works for most other components.

Comment: Server Manager in 2008 R2 can be used to administer remote systems, however you would need to be running the R2 version on your desktop (me thinks)